# setting system variables through terminal

Tags: command-line, system

I have added 2 fake users Alice and Bob to through  terminal. How to export java Home to that user's .bash_profile.

Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: Please explain what is your goal. Why do want to export `JAVA_HOME` to .bash_profile? It may help to find another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Please put JAVA_HOME in `/etc/profile` itself and then restart the machine

2) Or you will have to export in every user `~/.bashrc` and then source it.